# Icon not show properly in notification in audio_service flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, audio-service

I am using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) flutter package for playing audio on background and control from lock screen and notification bar. This is working fine. I just facing issue for icon which not showing in android while in iOS icon is showing but it's show too small. Attaching screenshoot below:

[Android Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aREF4.jpg)

[iOS Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iXp8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Notification icon in Android must be in white or black colored. Any other color than white or black won't be accepted & result in blank white square symbol. You can check [this website](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=360&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_360) for notification icon generate. Even You can check how Spotify app icon looks in Notification bar.